# Event Action<T> in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

In .net code I give the way for testers to choose how to work with application logs.
It looks like this

```
 public static event Action<string> DebugEvent;

    internal static void InvokeDebugEvent(string message)
    {
        DebugEvent?.Invoke(message);
    }
```

In log.cs I have

```
public static void WriteLog(string logMessage) {
        if (LogEnabled) {
            InvokeDebugEvent(logMessage);
        }
    }
```

and now I can do something like this(for example)

```
Core.DebugEvent+=System.Console.WriteLine;
```

or maybe this

```
Core.DebugEvent+=list.Add;
```

but if I try to do this in UWP I take error:

> Event add method .add_DebuEvent(System.Action) has a parameter of type 'System.Action'.  The parameters to event add methods must be Windows Runtime delegates. Was the module being exported compiled as a winmdmodule (/target:winmdobj) for Windows Metadata export?

How can I fix this..?

Comment: The same exact code does not work in UWP? This is strange. Could you please provide the full example and point where the error happens? This should work.

Comment: Hi, Have you created a class library that is not `Windows Runtime`? UWP is based on `Windows Runtime`, you need to create a class library that meets the requirements, such as `Class Library (Universal Windows)`.

Comment: Since your event is public, C# treats it as part of the public interface of a Windows Runtime component, but the events supported by the Windows Runtime [are limited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-csharp-and-visual-basic). You can declare a custom delegate that is compatible with the Windows Runtime, or you can declare the event private or internal to say that you don't want the event part of the Windows Runtime public interface.

Comment: 1)this is a shared project 2)the code is not written by me, I only need to add an interface for logs for testing (for this reason only public) 3)if you test this code in the class library (uwp) everything works well. How in uwp to delegate work with logs " outside"

Comment: Hi @EgorPetrov , What is the dependency framework of the shared project you are using? This error looks like a conversion error due to different target platforms. Can you provide the complete code for reference? I tested your code in a UWP project and it compiles normally